# Pandas: grouping and xticks in plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'm working with same date which has the following structure:

[image: data]

I want to group the data by the column `B`,and get the mean value for plot and compare.

```
sub_data = data_composite.groupby(['B']).aggregate(np.mean)
ax = sub_data.plot()
```

Obtaining:

[image: Plot result]

However, I would like to get the correspondent xticks in the figure. Which it will be KP40, KP08, etc... Something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do that?

Thank very much. Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

It should work for you

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tmp_labels = data_composite.drop_duplicates(subset='B', keep = 'first')
xlabels = tmp_labels['B'].values
plt.xticks(np.arange(sub_data.shape[0]),list(xlabels), rotation=90)
```

Comment: One question, would your code keep organised the data? 

Because if I do:

`sub_data.head(50)`

I see the code is organised according to column A (which the column B numbers only).

However, in the graph I obtained with your code, it is not in numerical order.

Comment: Thank very much! I removed the extra parenthesis!

Answer (score 0):

I found out this can be done easier using the index column as input for plt.xticks.

```
sub_data = data_composite.groupby(['B']).aggregate(np.mean)
ax = sub_data.plot()

ax.set_xlabel(x)
ax.set_ylabel('Quantity of {}'.format(y)) 

plt.xticks(np.arange(groupped_data.shape[0]),list(groupped_data.index), rotation=90);
```